# Knowing child collections count without loading them in NHIbernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with FluentNH. I've a simple class called PostCategory and it contains a collection of Posts. The PostCategory class contains a property called TotalActivePosts. When I load all the PostCategories I want the no. of active posts for each category to be populated in this property. How I can do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Vijaya Anand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I did it is by using a [computed property](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property). see item no. 5- arbitrary SQL.
you could use something like:

```
Select Count(*) from Posts where PostCategoryId = Id And IsActive = 1
```

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386981/fluent-nhibernate-and-computed-properties)

Comment: The link for computed property is 404

Answer (score 3):

You can either do what sJhonny recommends or use the `lazy="extra"` attribute on the mapping. That way you can just do Posts.Count to get just the count without loading all of the entities.

See this SO question:
[NHibernate Lazy="Extra"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079962/nhibernate-lazy-extra)

Comment: I'm using Fluent NHibernate. How and where I can specify this lazy="extra"? (NOTE: Currently many classes I'm using extra properties like TotalPosts, TotalComments that are tied with formulas in classes to know the count of child collections without loading them entirely. If I can avoid them using the lazy="extra" feature it is really great!)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option. nice..
although Jaguar mentions there that it's not an 'official' feature of the lazy="extra" option, and he found it to be buggy. so, perhaps it should be used with caution.

Comment: @Vijaya `HasMany(p => p.Posts).ExtraLazyLoad()`